# Does the Windows console support Hindi fonts?

Tags: windows-console

Does the Windows console support Hindi fonts? If yes, how does one type and what needs to be done to configure the console after installing Hindi fonts?

Comment: What happens when you select a Hindi font in the command-prompt properties window?

Comment: When I type using Hindi fonts "???????" prints.

Comment: FYI, cmd.exe has no idea what a font is. It's not the console.

Comment: You can implement font linking for Consolas, but the result is poor if the fallback font isn't a monospace font, e.g. falling back on Nirmala has poor text alignment.